# How do I pass source files between jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

My current setup consists of:

1. Project job - it's the one, that fetches the sources, deploys to the test environment and runs tests across the test env
2. Building job - it's a job that runs on a special machine which builds the sources into `deb` packages.

The issue: it's fairly easy to retrieve the `deb` packages from building job back (as a job artifact), but how would I pass the sources from project job to a building one?

They run on a different jenkins slaves.

What are the possible options?

Note: the building job isn't a specific job for this particular project. Several projects use it as a helper to build `deb` from the sources, so I cannot hardcode anything project-specific there.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [CloneWorkspace SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin)

Comment: Doesn't archive step happen in the end of the job? If so - the building job have to be triggered from the project job, which hasn't ended yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SVN, you might want to look at the [Tracking SVN Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tracking+SVN+Plugin).  This allows you to pull the same version out of SVN as another job.  We use this so that we can create both a "debug" and "release" build from the same SVN revision.  The debug version builds first.  If it succeeds, the release version is built using the same revision that was built for the debug.

Comment: No I don't - the code is retrieved from mercurial and pre-processed in the project job.